# Global Memory and CUDA streams

Tags: memory, cuda, cuda-streams

I'm working on CUDA and I have a doubt about global memory and streams CUDA.

Let:

```
__device__ float Aux[32];
__global__ void kernel1(...) {
    [...]
    Aux[threadIdx.y] = 0;
    [...]
}
```

So, if I run this kernel on different streams GPU. Is Aux the same for all streams? or there is a Aux variable for all streams being Aux global variable?
I can't find that information in the guide cuda.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same for all streams.

Streams control the (partial) order in which kernels are executed. They do not create new namespaces.